# Binding client to port asyncio python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

When trying to create a client to connect to a server, how do I define the client port, rather than having it assigned randomly?

As I want to do this using asyncio, and the client connects to the server using `asyncio.open_connection`, however the client port doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Basically I need the `socket.bind` function but for asyncio.

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html it's pretty straight forward, unless I misunderstand your question? `coroutine asyncio.open_connection(host=None, port=None, *, ...)` so that would be `asyncio.open_connection(your_host, port)`

Comment: that is the server host and port, I want to define the client host and port.

Comment: Why? This is a bad idea. It limits you to one client at a time, and to 2*MSL seconds between client connections unless you take other measures.

Comment: How? I am just defining the client port, I can have as many clients I want, but the ports will be predefined but different, rather than random.

Comment: Again I ask why? There is no benefit. Just let the system assign the local port. I don't know what you mean by 'how'?

Answer (score 0):

Can be set using `asyncio.open_connection(local_addr=(host, port))`